# ASP.NET how to call OnCommand from <li>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, html-lists

```
<asp:ListView ID="CategoryList" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <ul id="container">
         <li>
            <img src="<%# Eval("CategorieAfbeelding")%>" alt="">
            <p><%# Eval("CategorieNaam")%></p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In the above code, I want it so when I click the list item I trigger a function that gives the `<%# Eval("CategorieNaam")%>` to the code behind.

I usually use like this `OnCommand="btnMoreInfo_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategorieNaam")%>'` but this works on an ASP button and not on a list item.

I tried using the OnCommand function on the list item.
I also tried making an invisible asp button, but that's only gonna create a mess. it's not possible to put items inside an asp button either making it not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the button (or ImageButton) standard click event.

So, say this ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td><asp:Label ID="FighterLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fighter") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="EngineLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ThrustLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Thrust") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
            <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageView" runat="server" Width="200px"
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                OnClick="ImageView_Click"

                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="table table-hover">
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server">Fighter</th>
                <th runat="server">Engine</th>
                <th runat="server">Thrust</th>
                <th runat="server">Description</th>
                <th runat="server">View</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Note that, when possible, I much suggest using datakeys for a GridView, or ListView. The reason for this is you can then with ease get the database PK row value, but not have to expose or even show the database PK row value in the markup.

So, code behind to load above is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM Fighters ORDER BY Fighter");
        ListView1.DataBind();   
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

So, in above, we have a button click (image button).

The following shows how that simple button click event can get row information.

```
    protected void ImageView_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
        ListViewItem lvRow = (ListViewItem)btn.NamingContainer;

        Debug.Print($"Row index click = {lvRow.DisplayIndex}");

        int PK = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.DataKeys[lvRow.DisplayIndex]);

        Debug.Print($"Data base primary key value = {PK}");

        Debug.Print($"Image URL of button click = {btn.ImageUrl}");

        // get control value from the row.
        Label Engine = (Label)lvRow.FindControl("EngineLabel");
        Debug.Print($"Engine = {Engine.Text}");
        
    }
```

So, above shows how to get information such as the row index, the database PK value, or even how to pluck out controls from the given row.

ListView, Repeater, GridView etc. all support use of "naming container", and that will return the row click object.

In your sample markup, you don't show how the row click is occurring. However, as a general rule, any control(s) in which you are to pull current row values from?

Such controls should be server-side controls, have an "id" like most controls should, and thus you can use findcontrol to get the value from that given control.

In some cases, I will often for "ease" of coding make up on the fly some additional button attributes.

So, the above Image button click could have say this:

```
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageView" runat="server" Width="200px"
                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                OnClick="ImageView_Click"
                FighterName = '<%# Eval("Fighter") %>'
                PKID  = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                />
```

So, I "made up" the PKID and the FighterName attributes.

So, in code behind for the button click, I can thus simply use the "custom" attributes I add to the button click.

E.g.:

```
    protected void ImageView_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

        Debug.Print($"Fighter name = {btn.Attributes["FighterName"]}");  

        Debug.Print($"PKID = {btn.Attributes["PKID"]}");
```

So, in most cases, you can (and should) use the FindControl method of the row item. However, often I will “make up” and attach a few custom attributes to the row button for ease of use.

Comment: I am using it for a category selector so I wanted it to work when you click anywhere in the <li>. If that's not possible then replacing the image with an image seems to be the best option.